# How to view global variables while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

How can i watch global pointer variable root in Visual Studio Code?

Here is the sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node *root;
```

Comment: Add a watch on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enter debug mode (F5)

Add variable to watch (Right click on *root - Add to watch)

value will be shown in watch window during debug execution